# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" duplicate children added

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm working in a application using JavaFx, I want to duplicate my composant in a my `StackPane` and I have an error/exception.

```
final Button file = new Button("fichier");
file.setGraphic(new ImageView("/images/file.png"));
final Image fichier_img = new Image("/images/file.png");
final StackPane paint = new StackPane();

 ile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        File fichier = new File();
        paint.getChildren().addAll( mes_images[0]);
       //fichier.setPositionX(me.getSceneX());
    }
});
 paint.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
       public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)  
                menu_gauche.show(paint, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
        }
});
```

and Here is my error message:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children
>   added: parent = StackPane@658d001a at
>   javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mes_images[0]` is already added to the `StackPane`, which should not happen.
Create a new `Image` object (I guess it is an image) and add this new instance to the `StackPane` then everything will be fine.

From the [javadoc of `Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph.
>   Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the
>   following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of
>   a Parent, or as the clip of a Node.